# Solana Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1000078

Tags: typescript, token, solana

I get this when i try to create an AMM Pool using the 'ammCreatePool.ts' from raydium-sdk (https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk). I run the script directly using ts-node src/ammCreatePool.ts and modified it so it takes all neccessary variables as arguments (token_program_id, mint_address, name, symbol). I sadly can not find anything about this error besides the first program id being related to openbook and the second to raydium.
Here's the output:

```
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
(node:1282) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5921
      throw new SendTransactionError(
            ^
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1000078
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5921:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5880:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5829:14)
    at async sendTx (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/src/util.ts:36:18)
    at async buildAndSendTx (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/src/util.ts:64:10)
    at async ammCreatePool (/home/username/typescriptmakesmecry/Final/src/ammCreatePool.ts:91:19) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3443 of 799850 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]',
    'Program log: initialize2: InitializeInstruction2 { nonce: 254, open_time: 1710166950, init_pc_amount: 1, init_coin_amount: 100000000 }',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: SyncNative',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3045 of 780656 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2920 of 752943 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4501 of 738441 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3445 of 722339 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX invoke [2]',
    'Program srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX consumed 1357 of 696830 compute units',
    'Program srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX failed: custom program error: 0x1000078',
    'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 100934 of 796407 compute units',
    'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program error: 0x1000078'
  ]
}
```